# Need help to understand difference between $this and user defined value

Tags: jquery, class, this

I quick question concerning the value of the jquery variable "this".

I took some sample code shown below...

```
function blockHighlite()
{
//  alert ('block ' + $gCurrentClass + ' index ' + $gIndex);

        $(this).data('bgcolor', $(this).css('border-color'));
        $(this).css('border-color','rgba(255,128,0,.5)');
        $(this).css('border-color', $(this).data('bgcolor'));
  };
```

This code works fine to highlite the element border, but when I chage the code to point to a specific element like this, using global variables to represent the selected element it fails.
Am I not understanding the use of the "this" variable?  The variable $gCurrentClass and $gIndex are simply the class and index of my selected element.

```
function blockHighlite()
{
    alert ('block ' + $gCurrentClass + ' index ' + $gIndex);
        $gCurrentClass.eq[$gIndex].data('bgcolor', $gCurrentClass.eq[$gIndex].css('border-color'));
        $gCurrentClass.eq[$gIndex].css('border-color','rgba(255,128,0,.5)');
        $gCurrentclass.eq[$gIndex].css('border-color', $gCurrentClass.eq[$gIndex].data('bgcolor'));
  };
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `this` is not a jQuery variable, it's a javascript keyword referrencing, in this case, the element that the method was called on. Just replacing it with some random variables that are'nt even properly set won't work as there is no automagical reference to your classes or anything else.

Comment: Would you use parentheses after .eq, not square brackets?

Comment: How is `blockHighlite` used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$gCurrentClass` contains a string representing a classname, you need to pass it to the jQuery constructor (`$`) as a query selector. Try the following:

```
function blockHighlite()
{
    alert ('block ' + $gCurrentClass + ' index ' + $gIndex);
    $('.'+$gCurrentClass).eq($gIndex).data('bgcolor', $('.'+$gCurrentClass).eq($gIndex).css('border-color'));
    $('.'+$gCurrentClass).eq($gIndex).css('border-color','rgba(255,128,0,.5)');
    $('.'+$gCurrentclass).eq($gIndex).css('border-color', $('.'+$gCurrentClass).eq($gIndex).data('bgcolor'));
};
```

Comment: Seems unlikely that a var starting with `$` would simply contain a string. Typically it's a jQuery object reference.  I guess we need more info though!

Comment: @Madbreaks `The variable $gCurrentClass and $gIndex are simply the class and index of my selected element.` That's from the OP. To me, that sounds like a string, not a jQuery Object that references the class.

Comment: I tried this and still no love.  Any idea as what I am doing wrong?  Is it ok to use the .eq operator in my syntax? I am attaching the $ to the variable because I need global scope.

Comment: Yes, but you need to specify `.eq()` (with parentheses, not squared brackets).

Comment: Just changed to parentheses and still nothing. Sorry, I didn't see the updated code with '.'.  Works perfectly.  Can someone explain why I need the '.''s.

Comment: Because `.` is the selector for an element with the class name specified.

Comment: Thanks.  So its sort of like saying DOM.element(classname)?

Comment: Essentially. But you can pass any CSS selector. Check the API docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/